# Convert Scala List to List with another type

Tags: list, scala, pattern-matching

I want to create a more complex object type List from a simple type List. Eg, `List[String] => List[MyType]`.

I've given it three goes using map-based approaches. A simple map with wildcard:

```
> case class telecom (name:String, longitude:Double, latitude:Double)
defined class telecom
> List("foo","bar").map(x:String => telecom(x,0,0)):List[telecom]
:1: error: ';' expected but ')' found.
```

A pattern-matching method that uses the case class constructor:

```
> def foo(c:List[String]){                                                                              
 | c match {                                                                                             
 | case tc:List[telecom] => tc.map(telecom(_,0,0)):List[telecom]; println("matched telephonecomapny");
 | case _ => println("matched nothing"); throw new ClassCastException(); }}
warning: there were unchecked warnings; re-run with -unchecked for details
foo: (c: List[String])Unit

>  foo(List("foo","bar"))
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to usda.rd.broadband.model.DatabaseTables$TelephoneCompany
    at $anonfun$foo$1.apply(<console>:11)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:206)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:206)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:61)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:45)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:206)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:45)
    at .foo(<console>:11)
    at .<init>(<console>:11)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at RequestResult$.<init>(<console>:9)
    at RequestResult$.<clinit>(<console>)
    at RequestResult$scala_repl_result(<console...
```

and a simpler pattern-matching method:

```
> def bar(c:List[String]){
 | c match {
 | case tc:List[telecom] => tc 
 | case _ => println("matched nothing")}}
 warning: there were unchecked warnings; re-run with -unchecked for details
 foo: (c: List[String])Unit
> val r = bar(List("foo","bar"))
t: Unit = ()
```

Comment: Pattern matching matches _what is already there_.  You cannot use the act of matching to transform your data!  You're asking for, "Given a list of strings, _if they are already a list of telecoms_, then (blah blah)!"

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The first try is quite OK. You just forgot to use parenthesis around lambda function arguments. Instead of:

```
List("foo","bar").map(x:String => telecom(x,0,0)):List[telecom]
```

you should use:

```
List("foo","bar").map( (x:String) => telecom(x,0,0)):List[telecom]
```

or simpler:

```
List("foo","bar").map( x => telecom(x,0,0))
```

Comment: Nice, and doh! on my end. In my defense, if you had written the error message, it would have been "missing parens around lambda function arguments" and the correction would be obvious. Thanks!

Comment: casting to List[telecom] in first 2 examples is not necessary

Comment: @Tim: It is not a casting, it's a type ascription. It is indeed not necessary, the goal here is to "prove" that the resulting type is correct. Do you think the answer would be more clear if I had them removed ?

Comment: hm, right, I was confused with cast operator in PostgreSQL (::). Actually I haven't found if there is a cast operator in Scala. However, if you can update the answer with what ':List[telecom]' means, it would be great

Answer (score 29):

In the interest of one-upmanship, I must say it can be further reduced to

```
List("foo","bar").map(telecom(_,0,0))
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can make that:

```
List("foo","bar").map(x => telecom(x,0,0))
```